# D3 Geojson Globe performance too bad on mobile phone during drag and zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing only 3 paths. then also performance is too slow during drag for panning and zoom.

1) Land
2) States of US
3) Graticule

Not sure what is eating up the performance. Maybe it is the GeoJSON that I am using is killing it.

GeoJSON used is: https://jsonblob.com/ebb63996-f264-11e9-a437-a77258e9bb5d

The code that I have to draw a globe is below.

```
content.drawGlobe = function () {
        content.getD3GeoJson().then(function (worldJson) {
            const svgWidth = window.innerWidth - (utilityService.is_small_device()
                ? 0
                : parseFloat(AppConst.sideMenuWidth));
            const margin = utilityService.is_iphone()
                ? ChartConst.GraphConfig.marginMobile
                : ChartConst.GraphConfig.margin;
            const svgHeight = window.innerHeight - utilityService.getHeaderHeight() - 44;
            const width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
            projection.translate([width / 2, svgHeight / 2]);
            const svg = d3.select("#globe")
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (svgWidth) + " " + (svgHeight)) //class to make it responsive
                .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
                .style("background", "#010D12");
            const graticulePath = svg.append("path")
                .datum(graticule)
                .attr("class", "graticule")
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                .style("stroke-width", "0.1px")
                .style("opacity", "1");
            const land = window.topojson.feature(worldJson, worldJson.objects.countries);
            const states = window.topojson.feature(worldJson, worldJson.objects.states);
            const mapPath = svg.append("path").datum(land)
                .style("stroke", "#fff")
                .style("stroke-width", "1px")
                .style("fill", "#243E54");
            const statePath = svg.append("path").datum(states)
                .style("stroke", "#fff")
                .style("stroke-width", "1px")
                .style("fill", "#243E54")
                .style("stroke-dasharray", "5, 5");
            const sensitivity = 58;
            const render = function () {
                statePath.attr("d", geoPath);
                mapPath.attr("d", geoPath);
                graticulePath.attr("d", geoPath);
            };
            render();
            svg
                .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function () {
                    const rotate = projection.rotate();
                    const k = sensitivity / projection.scale();
                    projection.rotate([
                        rotate[0] + d3.event.dx * k,
                        rotate[1] - d3.event.dy * k
                    ]);
                    render();
                }))
                .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                    projection.scale(initialScale * d3.event.transform.k);
                    render();
                }));
        });

    };
```

Looks like this
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to address performance during zoom/drag events or initially as well?

Comment: @AndrewReid Performance issue during drag and zoom.

Comment: Inside SVG only 3 paths are drawn, I wonder how bad it will be when more stuff will be drawn.

Comment: It's not so much the number of paths rather the number of coordinates. Recalculating the projected coordinates and resampling the paths each tick of the drag/zoom is relatively expensive. Using the end of the drag/zoom only to redraw simplifies this, but only updates the globe on mouse up. I'm away from the computer at the moment, but will take a look later.

Comment: Yeah, dragend would reduce the calculations but will not have an effect like moving the globe. :-(

Comment: @AndrewReid I wonder if it has anything to do with WebGL ? Like instead of using d3 I should use threeJs of cesiumJS. But for that, I need to find if it is not something that I am doing wrong here that is the bottleneck